# Intercepting third party functions in android using AspectJ

Tags: java, android, aop, aspectj

I have been trying to intercept all the third party functions which are part of my application using aspectJ, but somehow am only able to intercept the functions declared by me and not the ones declared by third party libraries.

i am using this aspectJ gradle configuration referenced from [this tutorial](http://fernandocejas.com/2014/08/03/aspect-oriented-programming-in-android/).

Here's what my aspect looks like :

```
private static final String POINTCUT_METHOD = "execution(* *(..))";

@Pointcut(POINTCUT_METHOD) 
public void methodAnnotatedWithDebugTrace() {}

@Around("methodAnnotatedWithDebugTrace()") 
public Object weaveJoinPoint(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) 
            throws Throwable { 
    // ...
}
```

Is there any way by which we can start intercepting third party functions as well ??

Comment: You're showing gradle plugin but what does your Aspect look like ?

Comment: not sure exactly what does aspect mean  but if you are asking about the pointcut and joinpoint this is how it is 
private static final String POINTCUT_METHOD =
            "execution(* *(..))";
 and 
@Around("methodAnnotatedWithDebugTrace()")
    public Object weaveJoinPoint(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

So in short trying to intercept all the possible functions

Comment: what is the definition of methodAnnotatedWithDebugTrace ?

Comment: @Pointcut(POINTCUT_METHOD)
    public void methodAnnotatedWithDebugTrace() {
    }

is it the right definition ?.

Comment: Well the naming is bad, but it should work. What do you do inside your weaveJoinPoint method ?

Comment: So currently i am just logging the class name and the function name which are getting intercepted, all I am seeing are the functions defined inside the app. And its not intercepting any of the functions from the third party libraries.

Comment: To paraphrase another answer that has been given multiple times : 
> You can only weave your own code, meaning that if you want to intercept third party libraries you need to use "call(* *(..))" instead of "execution(* *(..))"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To paraphrase another answer that has been given multiple times :

> You can only weave your own code

Basically Aspects with android only works at compile time and will usually weave your own code. If you're using existing code for which you don't have source (like the Android framework for example), the compiler won't have access to modify those. In your case, you can only catch when your code is accessing the third party library.

Meaning that if you want to intercept third party libraries you need to use `"call(* *(..))"` instead of `"execution(* *(..))"`

Comment: You can weave any code, source code is not required for aspectj: https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw.html

Comment: Artem so do u mean to say that can do binary weaving in android as well ?

Answer (score 0):

You can weave third party libraries' code with [my gradle-aspectj plugin](https://github.com/Archinamon/GradleAspectJ-Android).
It's possible because of Transform API, which handles all project sources, not only `src/*` packages, but jars/aars, sub-modules too.
But beware using weaving of third party code, it may lead to unexpected behaviours.