# How to monitor method execution at third party library?

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I have task to somehow monitor method calling at logback library. I started doing it with spring aop. So, for instance, i should catch all methods execution at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger class. And there is my Aspect for it:

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class LogbackAspect {

    @Before(value = "execution(* ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.*(..))")
    public void getInfo(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
         System.out.println("+++++AOP " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
}
}
```

But it's not working for now, so, is there any possibility to intercept method execution with spring aop? Or there are some better ways to do it?

Comment: Spring AOP can be only used to intercept method calls happening to Spring beans. Please read through the documentation [seciton](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-spring-or-aspectj)

Comment: Slightly off-topic: Please don't use `@Configuration` together with `@Aspect`. The Spring configuration belongs into a separate configuration class, an aspect is not the right place for it. I see this anti-pattern over and over again here. (Probably one person started doing this without thinking much and everybody just uses copy & paste.) You should add `@Component` to the aspect instead.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer deduced based on the question that the method is not intercepted and my understanding that the point cut points to an external library class. I never posted this as an answer and the comment was a hint on what could be wrong. And there is no evidene here that the logger IS a spring-bean either

Answer (score 5):

> Unfortunately, you can only weave your own code.

Brendon's answer is incorrect because it is focused on Android. On platforms with normal Java like Windows, MacOS, Linux you can intercept third-party code, given the following conditions:

- You use full AspectJ, not Spring AOP. AspectJ can be used without Spring or also in Spring projects.
- You use LTW (load-time weaving), usually via JVM parameter `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar`, and configure *aop.xml* correctly.
- As an alternative you can use the AspectJ compiler *ajc* directly via command line or via *AspectJ Maven Plugin* in order to do binary weaving, i.e. weaving aspect code into your 3rd party library, creating new woven class files and re-packaging them into a new JAR. Then you would use that JAR in place of the original. *(BTW, this would also work for Android if the library is something you can deliver and install with your app and not some system class/library which cannot be replaced or overridden.)*

I recommend LTW over binary weaving if you have no restrictions using Java command line parameters. There is even a chapter in the Spring manual describing how to use it directly in Spring.

---

**Update:** Here is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing you how to do that in plain Java + AspectJ LTW.

Let's create an AspectJ project in Eclipse with installed AJDT (AspectJ Development Tools). Of course you can also create a Maven project with AspectJ Maven Plugin or even without because actually you do not need the AspectJ compiler if you use LTW via `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar`. My sample project has this structure (Eclipse layout, not Maven, I just did it quickly):

[image: Eclipse AspectJ project]

The file contents are as follows.

***src/de/scrum_master/app/Application.java***

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;

public class Application {
  private static final Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.info("Example log from {}", Application.class.getSimpleName());
  }
}
```

***src/logback.xml***

```xml
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

***src/de/scrum_master/aspect/LogbackAspect.aj (or simply LogbackAspect.java)***

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class LogbackAspect {
  @Before(value = "execution(* ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.*(..))")
  public void getInfo(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println(joinPoint);
  }
}
```

***src/META-INF/aop.xml***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aspectj>
  <aspects>
    <aspect name="de.scrum_master.aspect.LogbackAspect" />
  </aspects>
  <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo" />
</aspectj>
```

Now create a simple Java run configuration for `Application` and add the Java agent to the command line:

[image: AspectJ LTW run configuration]

Now run the program and the console log will be like this:

```
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.9.5 built on Thursday Nov 28, 2019 at 11:28:53 PST
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info using configuration /C:/Users/alexa/Documents/java-src/SO_AJ_LTW_Logback_60295366/bin/META-INF/aop.xml
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register aspect de.scrum_master.aspect.LogbackAspect
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(ch.qos.logback.classic.Level ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.getEffectiveLevel())' in Type 'ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger' (Logger.java:109) advised by before advice from 'de.scrum_master.aspect.LogbackAspect' (LogbackAspect.aj)
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(int ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.getEffectiveLevelInt())' in Type 'ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger' (Logger.java:113) advised by before advice from 'de.scrum_master.aspect.LogbackAspect' (LogbackAspect.aj)
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(ch.qos.logback.classic.Level ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.getLevel())' in Type 'ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger' (Logger.java:117) advised by before advice from 'de.scrum_master.aspect.LogbackAspect' (LogbackAspect.aj)
(...)
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(java.lang.Object ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.readResolve())' in Type 'ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger' (Logger.java:787) advised by before advice from 'de.scrum_master.aspect.LogbackAspect' (LogbackAspect.aj)
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info processing reweavable type de.scrum_master.aspect.LogbackAspect: de\scrum_master\aspect\LogbackAspect.aj
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info successfully verified type de.scrum_master.aspect.LogbackAspect exists.  Originates from de\scrum_master\aspect\LogbackAspect.aj
execution(void ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.setLevel(Level))
execution(void ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.setLevel(Level))
execution(String ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.toString())
execution(void ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.addAppender(Appender))
execution(Logger ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.getChildByName(String))
execution(Logger ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.createChildByName(String))
execution(Logger ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.getChildByName(String))
execution(Logger ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.createChildByName(String))
execution(Logger ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.getChildByName(String))
execution(Logger ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.createChildByName(String))
execution(Logger ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.getChildByName(String))
execution(Logger ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.createChildByName(String))
execution(void ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.info(String, Object))
execution(void ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_1(String, Marker, Level, String, Object, Throwable))
execution(void ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(String, Marker, Level, String, Object[], Throwable))
execution(String ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.getName())
execution(LoggerContext ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.getLoggerContext())
execution(void ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(ILoggingEvent))
execution(int ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(ILoggingEvent))
execution(int ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(ILoggingEvent))
execution(int ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(ILoggingEvent))
execution(int ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(ILoggingEvent))
execution(int ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(ILoggingEvent))
16:04:52.791 [main] INFO  de.scrum_master.app.Application - Example log from Application
```

I think this is exactly what you want. Please refer to the [Spring manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) in order to find out how to configure AspectJ LTW there.

Comment: Is that true? I thought we could pointcut into *any* spring-bean using spring aspects.

Comment: The OP wants to intercept executions inside Logback, not into Spring beans. This is why both the question title and my answer mention **3rd party code**, the latter being beyond the power of Spring AOP.

Comment: Please note my massive update with complete MCVE + Eclipse screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Check this other answer out [Intercepting third party functions in android using AspectJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39189454/intercepting-third-party-functions-in-android-using-aspectj)

Unfortunately, you can only weave your own code.

However, depending on what you actually need to do with Logback, you could create a custom Appender and do what you need to in there?

**UPDATE**

Seeing as you want to record some form of metric of these exceptions, you could configure a StatusListener according to the logstash-logback docs

https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#status-listeners

With this, you could receive the event, and record whatever metrics you need

Comment: Thx for an answer. I have a LogstashTcpSocketAppender with a ringBuffer. In some ways our logstash shutting down, so ringBuffer overflows at some moment. I have walked through the logback code, found a method in which logback checks size of ringbuffer and starts drop events. I would like to somehow catch that moment, when ringBuffer overflows and make some metrics how many and witch events dropped.